# No description on approve page when I use the PayPal REST API

Tags: api, rest, paypal

Using the PayPal REST API, I'm passing in this to new payments:

**URL:** https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

**Request:**

```
{
    "intent":"sale",
    "payer":{
        "payment_method":"paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls":{
        "return_url":"[return_path]",
        "cancel_url":"[cancel_path]"
    },
    "transactions":[
        {
            "amount":{
                "total":"19.95",
                "currency":"USD",
                "details":{
                    "subtotal":"19.95"
                }
            },
            "description":"[product description]"
        }
    ]
}
```

But on the PayPal approve page I see no any order info. In "Your order summary" section at the left I see no description, no total, no subtotal, nothing.

Screenshot: http://goo.gl/dxoicB

But I expect to see there at lest smth...

How can I make individual items with descriptions in the REST API checkout? Or what I'm doing wrong? It seems I've read the whole [Developers Guide](http://goo.gl/zBGk5x), but there is nothing about it.

And another thing: when I done with order, in transaction details also is no any technical info about order.

Screenshot: http://goo.gl/i4iGHZ

There is no technical information allows us to understand what site and what product was sold there.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the `item_list` on `transactions` to get order summary.

Example request data

```
{
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://return.url",
        "cancel_url": "http://cancel.url"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "item",
                "sku": "item",
                "price": "1.00",
                "currency": "USD",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "1.00"
        },
        "description": "This is the payment description."
    }]
}
```

Refer:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#transaction-object

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs/blob/master/samples/payment/create_with_paypal.js#L16

Comment: But if you do this the description will not longer be shown in the order summary.